# Python DataFrame: How to continue grouping by after several operation on Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with states, counties and population statistics with the below columns:

```
SUMLEV  REGION  DIVISION  STATE  COUNTY   STNAME  CTYNAME CENSUS2010POP
```

And with the below line I am grouping the dataframe and sorting for each state the county population

`sorted_df = temp_df.groupby(['STNAME']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['CENSUS2010POP'], ascending = False))`

After the sorting I want to only keep the 3 largest counties population-wise

```
largestcty = sorted_df.groupby(['STNAME'])["CENSUS2010POP"].nlargest(3)
```

And as the next step I would like to sum the values there witrh the below command

```
top3sum = largestcty.groupby(['STNAME']).sum()
```

But the problem now is that the key 'STNAME' is not in the series after the group by. My question is how to preserve the keys of the original DataFrame in the series?

So after applying the answer I have `top3sum` as a dataframe

`top3sum = pd.DataFrame(largestcty.groupby(['STNAME'])'STNAME','CENSUS2010POP'].sum(),columns =['CENSUS2010POP'])

top3sum[:8]`

`>>>
STNAME CENSUS2010POP

Alabama    1406269
Alaska      478402
Arizona     5173150
Arkansas    807152
California  15924150
Colorado    1794424
Connecticut 2673320
Delaware    897934`

This is how the top3sum data look like and then I am getting:
`cnty = top3sum['CENSUS2010POP'].idxmax()`

And `cnty = California`
But then trying to use the cnty with `top3sum['STNAME']` I am receiving a key error

Comment: Please show what you mean with sample data. You would not be able to retain original indices since you aggregate. Are you looking for `reset_index()`?

Comment: I used reset_index() and I understand that the index is gone after aggregation but my question is how to recreate new index based on old keys in a new dataframe.

Comment: Would have been helpful to see original data and desired results. Not sure what you mean by *keys*.

Comment: Or Atleast have the  `['STNAME'] ` back as my index since after grouping for the Statename I have the states still in the result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is, that after the second grouping, you only select the column `CENSUSxxx` and pick the three largest values.

Please note that you don't need to sort in advance before applying nlargest, so the first command is unnecessary. But if you sort, you can easily pick the first 3 lines of the sorted grouped dataframes:

```
largestcty = temp_df.groupby(['TNAME']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['CENSUS2010POP'], ascending = False).head(3)
```

Then you need to adopt the sum command in order to select your desired column:

```
top3sum = largestcty.groupby(['STNAME'])['CENSUS2010POP'].sum()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. This is very helpful. But If I only select the column 'CENSUS2010POP' why do I still have the statenames in the series `largestcty` but they are not anymore accessible as a key?

Comment: One more question I have is how to give the created series after the group by and applying the `.sum()`  the `top3sum` still has `['STNAME']` as a key.